Convergence - indicator function
Can someone explain why the following sequence converges to zero
$f_n(x)=n1_{[0,1/n]}(x)$
To me it looks like a rectangle with an area of $1$ regardless of how large $n$.

For any $x>0$ there is $n_0$ such that for $n\ge n_0$, $1/n<x$, hence $f_n(x)=0$. By the way, at $x=0$ the function converges to $\infty$.

It converges point wise to $0$ for any $x>0$. Just give it a try with some values.

The function converges pointwise to zero everywhere except $x = 0$, but it does not converge uniformly.
To show that it converges pointwise, pick a real number $x \neq 0$. Then you will always be able to find an integer $N$ such that when $n \geq N$ you have $f_n(x) = 0$. That proves that $f_n \rightarrow 0$ pointwise. On the other hand, at $x = 0$ the function diverges to infinity.
To show that it does not converge uniformly, choose any $\epsilon > 0$. Then if you pick an integer $N \geq \epsilon^{-1}$, for any $n \geq N$ you can find a value of $x$ for which $f_n(x) > \epsilon$, proving that $f_n$ does not converge to 0 uniformly.
